# Does it make sense to return shareReplay from defer?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex, reactive-extensions-js

I was trying to utilize `observables` in authentication routine in my sample app which I'm building to learn `ReactiveX`, while looking for examples I've found a neat and also well in-code commented gist ([@alxhub](https://gist.github.com/alxhub/1fa85d0b8ef0286b617566e65a0011b4), thanks!) that shows how an authentication service along with interceptor could be organized, but I can't wrap my head around what's happening in there, probably due to luck of experience...
The relevant portion of code is:

```
this.refreshToken = Observable.defer(() => {
  // Defer allows us to easily execute some action when the Observable
  // is subscribed. Here, we set the current token to `null` until the
  // refresh operation is complete. This ensures no requests will be
  // sent with a known bad token.
  this.subject.next(null);

return this
  // Next, we refresh the token from the server.
  .doRefreshToken()
  // Set it as the active token.
  .do(token => this.subject.next(token))
  // Drop the value, ensuring this Observable only completes when
  // done and doesn't emit.
  .ignoreElements()
  // Finally, share the Observable so we don't attempt multiple
  // refreshes at once.
  .shareReplay();
});
```

which then used in interceptor like this:

```
.catch((err, restart) => {
  // If the request is unauthorized, try refreshing the token before restarting.
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
    return Observable.concat(this.auth.refreshToken, restart);
  }
  throw err;
})
```

As I understand `defer` creates a separate `observable` for each `observer`, so why do they bother to `shareReplay`? In what occasion there will be more than one `observer` on the newly created `observable`?

Now, I wanted to to show a login dialog in case of `401`, but only one for a batch of requests, and it seems that `shareReplay` is the way to go, so I thought to put the dialog open code inside `doRefreshToken` but if it gonna be inside `defer` I'll get as much dialogs as number of unauthenticated requests I presume, so how I should organize it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `shareReplay` in `refreshToekn` doesn't make sense since as you said it is emitted from defer which creates new stream each time. I assume with or without it, the code will run the same.

You can create an observable like below and assign to a variable and attach to the `concat`. This `shareReplay` will only emit once.

```
const openDialog=
   of(true).pipe(map(e=>{
 console.log("open dialog") 
 return e 
}),shareReplay(1))
```

and in catch

```
.catch((err, restart) => {
  // If the request is unauthorized, try refreshing the token before restarting.
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
    return Observable.concat(this.auth.refreshToken,openDialog, restart);
  }
  throw err;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I'm not sure that I've got your idea, you `concat` `openDialog` after `refreshToken`, this way if I understand correctly, the dialog will open only once in a lifetime of the app, but the token will be refreshed several timers if we have several failed requests...

Comment: yes you are correct, you can save refreshToken() and shareReplay() to another variable (but not using defer()) like how openDialog is done.